# What are some good resources for learning algorithm optimization?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've been tinkering around with code (*Basic, Python, C++, PHP, JavaScript*) on and off for almost two decades, but have only recently begun to get more "serious" about it (*using Java*). I can write code to do what I want, but now I want to learn to optimize my programs to run faster (looping through an array for every element in an array can get slow very quickly, etc). What I don't want is to be popping onto this site every 5 minutes for every little question I have. I want to learn to answer my own questions.

That said, what are some good resources for learning algorithm analysis and optimization?

I have a copy of **Data Structures and Algorithms in Java** (3rd edition) but I feel it's written to mostly be incorporated into a college curriculum and isn't very easy to use sans-professor. The book also has a tendency to over-use abbreviations, making it hard to flip to a particular chapter without having to skim back through the book to understand what each abbreviation stands for.

I do have some knowledge of Calculus, but it's extremely rusty, so I would prefer resources that give more explanation and fewer formulas.

Thank you in advance for all the help you can give!

Comment: "Doesn't feel like a current-SO question", however, since it fits with the once-upon-a-time-not-closed-immediately questions by some well-known-SO-users and seems well written, I shan't close it, excepting a duplicate.

Comment: @pst Thank you for not closing the question outright. I debated even asking this since I felt it might be too vague, but after looking for resources on my own for a week, I decided to just go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend enough Michael Abrash's "The Zen of Code Optimization". It's easyto read and full of insights.    The parts that focus on pre-pentium x86 are dated, but it's real value is the focus on how to think about making code faster.

I believe it's out of print, but you may find a used copy online.

Comment: The book is a bit dated (PRE-Pentium x86?!), but basic principles should stay relatively unchanged. The book does seem to be out of print, but I can see some copies available around the web. I think I'll purchase this based on your answer and the wikipedia article on Michael Abrash.

Answer (score 1):

You might start with Skiena's [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/). The same author also has a book on puzzle-solving called [Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638), which gives you a more entertaining way to get practice with algorithms than slogging through a textbook.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had come across Skiena's **Algorithm Design Manual** previously when looking around Amazon.com, but passed over it. I'll have to give it another look. Thank you!